# Java - Iterator that might fail

Tags: java, exception, iterator

as described in the title, I am trying to design an iterator over some data, which might fail somewhere down the line. An example would be an `Iterator<DatabaseObject>` that would, upon the call to `next()` read in the next row from DB and proceed. Other examples might include processing data using objects from API that raise Exception. The question is how to respond in this scenario, as Iterator is not allowed to raise any exceptions... Should we throw `NoSUchElementException` and provide meaningful message there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can throw an unchecked exception. It makes sense to throw `NoSuchElementException`, since, in fact, an error prevented there from being such an element.

It would be nice if the exception would wrap any underlying exception. Unfortunately, `NoSuchElementException` does not have a constructor that takes another exception. So if you want to propagate the underlying cause up, you'll have to go a different route, such as throwing a `RuntimeException`:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (<some exception type> e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Next element not accessible", e);
}
```

Alternatively, you could return some reserved value (such as `null`).

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that it depends on how you want to handle the error.
Perhaps you want to read the next entry already in hasNext(), so you can return false when a problem occurs. 
Think about it from a client perspective.
How should the client react?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the APIs I've seen that try to make "Iterators that can fail" really just end up working very badly.  I'd strongly recommend that you just *don't use an `Iterator` for this.*